# Is there an option to use options in normal mode always in small caps?

Tags: vim

I'm one of those few people who still uses caps lock regularly (*Oh, the horror!! aaaah :O)*

The problem however with that is that I often forget to turn them off, before switching to Vim's normal mode and `dd` has a different meaning than `DD`.

Is there an option in Vim that will *force* it to take commands in normal mode always as they were typed in small caps? So if I `DD` it thinks of it as `dd`.

Comment: How would you use the CAPS commands? D, Y, G, P - I couldn't live without them

Comment: I see. You just want it to behave as without CAPS. So, shift should still work to get capital letters

Comment: @sehe - With shift :) (2nd comment): Yes, that's right. I almost always use shift-D when I want to use D.

Answer (score 1):

See `:he i_CTRL-^`

To use Ctrl-^ to toggle "Caps Lock", place the following in your vimrc (or just yank the lines in Vim, then type :@" to execute them):

```
" Execute 'lnoremap x X' and 'lnoremap X x' for each letter a-z.
for c in range(char2nr('A'), char2nr('Z'))
  execute 'lnoremap ' . nr2char(c+32) . ' ' . nr2char(c)
  execute 'lnoremap ' . nr2char(c) . ' ' . nr2char(c+32)
endfor
```

Since the idea is to allow you to forget about capslock, it may also be desirable to automatically turn off this special mode when exiting insert mode:

```
" Kill the capslock when leaving insert mode.
autocmd InsertLeave * set iminsert=0
```

Note the use of the '`iminsert`' option. Pressing <kbd>C-^</kbd> actually toggles this option between 0 and 1, which automatically enables or disables your language maps. A related option, '`imsearch`', controls the mappings while entering a search pattern.

### Using a Keymap

An alternative procedure that also causes Ctrl-^ to toggle "Caps Lock", is to use a keymap (this is not a mapping; see :help mbyte-keymap).

Using the 'keymap' option keeps vimrc clean and adds an indicator to the status line while in this "Caps Lock" mode.

See for details: [wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert-mode_only_Caps_Lock)

Answer (score 1):

There is this vim plugin, [capslock.vim : Software Caps Lock](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1725), which use mappings, similar to sehe first solution, but it can work as Caps Lock in normal mode as well.

By default, this plugin automatically disabled Caps Lock  behavior when leaving insert mode.
This can be changed with `let g:capslock_persist = 1`.

You can set the key used to activate the plugin something like

```
imap <C-L>     <Plug>CapsLockToggle
nmap <Leader>l <Plug>CapsLockToggle
```